# Javascript functions to print SIMPLE

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function

I am new to programming and can not figure out why the innerHTML function will not print a value on the screen (I realized I used two functions and it seems extra for this small amount of code but it is because it is for a larger project)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="moneyform" name="moneyform">
        <fieldset>
            <select id="money" name="money" onselect="calculateTotal()">
                <option value="loon">1 dollar</option>
                <option value="toon">2 dollar</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <p id="pg"></p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="TEST.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

//JAVASCRIPT BELOW

var moneyprice = new Array();
moneyprice["loon"] = 1;
moneyprice["toon"] = 2;

function moneyTotal() {
    var mons = 0;
    var frm = document.forms["moneyform"];
    var selectedMoney = frm.elements["money"];
    mons = moneyprice[selectedMoney.value]

    return mons;
}

function calculateTotal() {
    var total = moneyTotal();

    document.getElementById("pg").innerHTML = total;

}
```

Comment: Where/how do you call the `calculateTotal()` function?

Comment: sorry i meant to put the calculateTotal() function where the moneyTotal() is in the html file i will edit

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right path in `src` attibute of the script tag?

Comment: Just change `onselect` to `oninput` or `onchange` and your code should work: http://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/uv4eg5bx/6/.  `onselect` is fired when you select text in an input (ie. highlight the text with your cursor).

Comment: Thanks Turnip worked perfect

Comment: @abe - You deleted another question while I was answering. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182832/help-abe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are using the `onselect` event to kick things off, but [`select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onselect) is for when text inside of a `text` field or `textarea` is selected by the user. You'll want to use the `change` event, which triggers when the value of an element changes.

Next, you aren't working with your Array properly and it's causing your result to come back as nothing. Arrays have non-negative integer indexes where data can be stored. They don't have key names to store data in - - Objects do that. You can see here that after these lines run, you still have an empty Array:

```js
var moneyprice = new Array();  // Ok.

// moneyprice doesn't/can't have a "loon" or a "toon" index
// so neither of these lines accomplish anything
moneyprice["loon"] = 1;        
moneyprice["toon"] = 2;

console.log(moneyprice); // Empty array

// ******************************************

// Now, this is how to use an array:
var moneyprice2 = new Array();  // Ok.

// You interact with an Array via its numeric indexes:
moneyprice2[0] = "loon";        
moneyprice2[1] = "toon";

console.log(moneyprice2); // Empty array
```

Now, it's not clear as to what you are trying to do with that Array anyway and it seems that what you are attempting to do doesn't really make much sense - your functions talk about money and calculating totals, but your `select` has string values.

Lastly, the code you are using uses ancient techniques that you really shouldn't get too comfortable using. There's a lot of bad code out there, so learn from a reputable source. [The Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML) is one.

See this scaled back solution to give you an idea of the "moving parts" to get something up and running. Notice how all the JavaScript is separated from the HTML.

```js
// Get your element references the proper way.
// No need to get a reference to the form, just to get a reference
// to the select and even if we did want to get a reference
// to the form, we use the modern DOM API to do it (not document[forms]).
let select = document.getElementById("money");
let pg = document.getElementById("pg");

// Set up event handlers in JavaScript, not with HTML attributes
select.addEventListener("change", calculateTotal);

function calculateTotal() {
  // .innerHTML should only be used when the string you are dealing with
  // contains HTML that needs to be parsed as such. When there isn't any
  // HTML, use .textContent
  pg.textContent = select.value;
}
```

```html
<form id="moneyform">
  <fieldset>
    <select id="money" name="money">
      <option value="loon">1 dollar</option>
      <option value="toon">2 dollar</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <p id="pg"></p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```